# static files failing to load: net::err_content_length_mismatch

Tags: http, tomcat, nginx

Some static files are not loading properly browser. I am seeing ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH status. I am using tomcat server with Nginx proxy. This is the error I found  in logs `2018/08/06 13:19:14 [crit] 19272#19272: *164 open() "/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/6/01/0000000016" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream,`

How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the SSL buffer size to 4k:

```
ssl_buffer_size 4k;
```

Documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_buffer_size

In my project, the error `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` in the browser appeared due to an error inside the openssl library.
Error in biginteger library. I was helped by reducing the buffer.